# Point in parallelogram in 3d space

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, 3d

I am trying to determine if a point $P$ is in a parallelogram.

The parallelogram is defined by $3$ points $A, B, C$.

Point $P$ lies on the same plane as the parallelogram.

I am trying to use fact if $s$ and $t$ are in $[0,1]$ then $P$ is in the parallelogram but I do not know how to solve, $AP = s \cdot AB + t \cdot AC$ for $s$ and $t$.

Comment: What has happened to the previous (half an hour ago) almost identical question to which I had given a comment which was almost an answer ?

Comment: A necessary and sufficient condition is that $s,t \in [0,1]$...

Comment: Rather than $P$, more like $\vec{AP} = s\cdot\vec{AB} + t\cdot \vec{AC}$ in vectors.

Comment: @peterwhy It's exactly what I said to the OP in the previous version !

Comment: Please, answer me...

Comment: @JeanMarie Oh, I didn't see OP's previous question, and can't find it in their profile.

Comment: @peterwhy The "answer me" was directed to the OP... you couldn't guess of course...

Comment: @ChrisKouts If you know the coordinates of the 4 points, that equation becomes a system of 3 linear equations (3 dimensions) in 2 unknowns ($s,t$).

Comment: @peterwhy I'm trying to implement this with c++ using the Eigen library. Therefore I'm looking for a clean formula to define s and t, but I guess introducing a solver is the only way. I was hoping there was geometrical trick that involving a determinant but maybe I'm wrong.

Answer (score 1):

As I said you in my previous comment, the identity should be:

$$\vec{AP} = s\cdot \vec{AB} + t\cdot \vec{AC}$$

Written under the form  $P-A=s(B-A)+t(C-A)$, it gives rise to this linear  system with the two first equations with $x$ and $y$ coordinates (the third one with $z$ coordinates being redundant if $P$ is in the plane defined by $A,B,C$);

$$\begin{cases}P_x-A_x=s (B_x-A_x)+t(C_x-A_x)\\
P_y-A_y=s (B_y-A_y)+t(C_y-A_y)
\end{cases}$$

Solve it by using Cramer's formulas for $s$ and $t$, then test whether $0 \le s,t \le 1$.

Comment: The $z$ equation can be necessary if the plane of parallelogram is parallel to the $yz$- or $xz$-plane. (I think more generally also when the $z$ direction is on the plane of the parallelogram)

Comment: Is there a way to introduce determinant to simplify solution similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1217585/parallelogram-contains-point
Or would the determinant be introduce after using Cramer's formula?

Comment: Cramer's formulas are the formula given in the reference $s = -det(PA, PQ)/det(PQ, PR), \ \ 
t = det(PA, PR)/det(PQ, PR)$